# SENCHA TOUCH native packaging for android

Tags: extjs, touch

I have a sencha touch app using 2.3.0 version.
I am trying to run:
sencha app package build myappsmobile.json

I have done all what the documentation is asking (android sdk and the json file and ruby and so on)

I am doing it on windows.

I am getting errors related to java maybe:
here is the complete log of the error:
Any ideas?

```
Sencha Cmd v4.0.0.203
[ERR]

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 18.1.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for InteractionAnalyticsMobile...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.0.3
[gettarget] API level:        15
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Work\SenchaTouch\GettingStarted\build\bin\res
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Work\SenchaTouch\GettingStarted\build\bin\rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Work\SenchaTouch\GettingStarted\build\bin\rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Work\SenchaTouch\GettingStarted\build\gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Work\SenchaTouch\GettingStarted\build\bin\classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Work\SenchaTouch\GettingStarted\build\bin\dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for InteractionAnalyticsMobile...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to D:\Work\SenchaTouch\GettingStarted\build\bin\classes

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\pdayan\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130717\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130717\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\pdayan\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130717\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130717\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Error running javac.exe compiler

Total time: 3 seconds
""C:\Users\pdayan\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130717\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130717\sdk\tools\android" create project --target android-15 --name InteractionAnalyticsMobile --activity STActivity --path "D:\Work\SenchaTouch
Can not open destination file for writing
Can not open destination file for writing
Could not run ant with error: 1
Failed to package application
Copy operation failed src=D:\Work\SenchaTouch\GettingStarted\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build
build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\AndroidManifest.xml
Copy operation failed src=D:\Work\SenchaTouch\GettingStarted\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build
\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\assets\build\ant.properties

[ERR] stbuild exited with non-zero code : 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling "C:\Program files\Sencha Cmd" and again re-installing it at "C:\Sencha" without any spaces in folder name.and it will worked.

Comment: it doenst let me do it. I can only choose the path.In addition I doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: IT DOESNT HELP EITHER/

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?273115-Packaging-application-exit-ERR-stbuild-exited-with-non-zero-code-7 check that link also official forum of sencha

Answer (score 0):

try using backward slashes in the paths mentioned in the config.json file,path to the certificate, android sdk path all should be changed ..ex: d:/android/android_sdk_path

Answer (score 0):

The path to the SDK should have some escape like this.(windows version)

```
    "sdkPath":"D:\/android-sdks"
```